# Regarding probability density functions of two consecutive events

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say, the probability density function (PDF) of when I throw a ball with respect to time is an exponential decaying function. Say I throw two balls. When time starts (t=0), the PDF of throwing the first ball is an exponentially decaying function. After I have thrown the first ball, the PDF of throwing the second with respect to time elapsed since the first ball was actually thrown is also an exponentially decaying function. Now, if ask the question when was the second ball thrown in absolute time, what would its PDF be? It can't be the product of the two exponentials because that would decay faster than either of them. My intuition is that the PDF should decay but at a rate slower than either of them.

P.S. this is not a homework question. I am working with avalanche photodiodes and have a similar problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_1$ be the random variable for the time the first ball is thrown. Let $T_2$ be the random variable for the time the second ball is thrown after the first. The total time elapsed between t=0 and the throwing of the second ball is the random variable $T = T_1 + T_2$. This is a convolution of two exponential random variables. Its pdf for T is calculated as follows:
$$h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t_1|\lambda_1) \, f(t-t_1|\lambda_2) \, dt_1 $$
where $f(t|\lambda)=\lambda \,e^{-\lambda\,t}$ for $t\ge0$ and zero otherwise. The limits simplify to
$$h(t) = \int_{0}^t f(t_1|\lambda_1) \, f(t-t_1|\lambda_2) \, dt_1 $$
For the case $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$:
$$h(t) = {\lambda_1\lambda_2\over\lambda_2-\lambda_1} \left( e^{-\lambda_1\,t} - e^{-\lambda_2\,t}\right)$$ 
and otherwise for $\lambda=\lambda_1=\lambda_2$
$$h(t) = \lambda^2\,t \,e^{-\lambda\,t}$$